# Handle input array in one job step

Tags: snakemake

I have a rule which takes an array of fastq files from a method and turns them into symlinks to make handling them easier independent of their name. The problem is that in its current form the rule is executed for each output file...  how can I make it such that the rule is only executed once for each species?

I have the folowing rule:

```
rule mksymlink:
    input:
        file_list = lambda wildcards: get_fqfiles(wildcards.species)
    output:
        link=temp(dynamic(path.join(symlinkDir, "{species}_{rep}_R{n}")))
    message:
        "linked {output.link}"
    script:
        "scripts/Symlinks.py"
```

Comment: Why do you need `dynamic` ?

Comment: I don't it was just to test for solving the problem, the output isn't exactly dynamic if you know the input but I get x symlinks for x files the input function delivers and I was hoping for some magic behind the curtains - it didn't do anything though

Comment: You should probably show the content of you `get_fqfiles` function. And also can you confirm the `Symlinks.py` script is supposed to make one symlink for every file in `input.file_list`?

Comment: I'm guessing a possible source of problem: you want your rule to create several symlinks for a given species: one for each combination of `rep` and `n` wildcards. So the `output` section of the rule should "expand" over these two wildcards. Otherwise the rule will be called for every possible such wildcards combination. To solve your problem, we will likely need to know what values the `rep` and `n` wildcards can take.

Answer (score 1):

Given what I understand from your problem, here is how I would proceed:

```python
# Adjust the possible values given your situation,
# possibly via globbing on pre-existing files,
# or reading the configuration of your pipeline
REPS = [1, 2, 3]
NS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def source_fq(species, rep, n):
    # Compute the path to the source fastq file
    fq_path = ...
    return fq_path

def get_fqfiles(wildcards):
    file_list = []
    for rep in REPS:
        for n in NS:
            file_list.append(source_fq(wildcards.species, rep, n))


rule mksymlink:
    input:
        file_list = get_fqfiles,
    output:
        # Note the double braces for species
        links = expand(
            path.join(symlinkDir, "{{species}}_{rep}_R{n}")),
            rep=REPS, n=NS)
        # Alternatively, use allow_missing=True
        # See https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-don-t-want-expand-to-use-every-wildcard-what-can-i-do
    message:
        "linked {output.links}"
    script:
        "scripts/Symlinks.py"
```

It might be more complicated, depending on the way `REPS` and `NS` depend or not on `species`.

Comment: ah yes I should have mentioned the rep problem, rep is variable depending on how many files there are provided for each species... which is a problem since I can't find a way to read them inside the output declaration...

Comment: @ChristianO. If the number of files is determined as a result of the execution of some rules, you should use a more complicated feature of Snakemake called "checkpointing". Otherwise, there may be a way to determine this in python code outside of rules, for instance using globbing on pre-existing files.